# How to subset the rows of my data frame based on a list of names?

Tags: r

I have a gene expression count data set with 2 columns and ~60000 rows. Each column is a sample and each row is a gene represented by an ensembl ID. I need to reduce or subset by data to include only genes that are protein coding. Here is a small scale example of what I would like to achieve:

Here is my data set called `BDC` containing the ensembl ID's of various types of genes along with the count data for each sample:

```
ENSEMBL           Sample A    Sample B
ENSG00000198888      10          2
ENSG00000210082      3           13
ENSG00000198763      6           18
ENSG00000198886      12          11
```

I also have a list of ensembl ID's called `ProtCod` that contain genes that I know are protein coding:

```
ENSEMBL_Protein_Coding
ENSG00000198888
ENSG00000198763
```

So I want to subset my data set to only include rows that have a protein coding ensembl ID and exclude all other rows:

```
ENSEMBL           Sample A    Sample B
ENSG00000198888      10          2
ENSG00000198763      6           18
```

But I need to achieve this on the large scale reducing my data set from ~60000 to ~20000 rows or genes.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
BDCProtCod <- BDC[!row.names(BDC) %in% ProtCod, ]
BDCProtCod
dim(BDCProtCod)
[1] 60675 2
```

The dimensions are the same as my original `BDC` data set, why isn't this code excluding the rows that don't contain names from `ProtCod`?

I've also tried:

```
BDCProtCod <- BDC[unlist(ProtCod), ]
BDCProtCod
dim(BDCProtCod)
[1] 19603 2
```

This actually excludes the rows I want to be excluded but it sets everything to "NA".

Comment: Please provide output of `str(ProtCod)` since it does not appear to be a plain list or character vector but a dataframe of one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've deleted your previous post as I was halfway writing the answer.

It seems like the ID is stored as `ENSEMBL` in `BDC` and `ENSEMBL_Protein_Coding` in `ProtCod`, so to get them as vectors you should call them as `BDC$ENSEMBL` and `ProtCod$ENSEMBL_Protein_Coding` respectively

```r
BDC[BDC$ENSEMBL %in% ProtCod$ENSEMBL_Protein_Coding, ]

  ENSEMBL         SampleA SampleB
  <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>
1 ENSG00000198888      10       2
2 ENSG00000198763       6      18
```

Data:

```r
require(readr)
BDC = readr::read_table("ENSEMBL           SampleA    SampleB
ENSG00000198888      10          2
ENSG00000210082      3           13
ENSG00000198763      6           18
ENSG00000198886      12          11")
ProtCod = readr::read_table('ENSEMBL_Protein_Coding
ENSG00000198888
ENSG00000198763')
```

Comment: Sorry about that, no one was answering so I'd re-post it. But thank you, that worked perfectly for me!